# Duda en implementación de Axios en Peticiones POST con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Tengo un ejercicio simple de sumar 2 números a través de un form que va desde html a php, de ahí me retorna el resultado; para que no se recargue la página uso axios y para mostrar los datos uso VueJS

Como muestro a continuación

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Hola</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app" >
    <form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent>
      <input type="text" v-model="numero1" name="numero1" />Primer Número
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" v-model="numero2" name="numero2" />Segundo Número
      <br><br>
      <button @click="sumaNumeros">Suma los Números</button>
    </form>
    {{ resultado }}
 </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
   new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
      numero1: '',
      numero2: '',
      resultado: ''
    },
    methods:{
      sumaNumeros: function(){
        axios.post('almacena.php', {
          numero1: this.numero1,
          numero2: this.numero2
        }).then((response) => {
          this.resultado = response.data
        })
      }
    },
    created: function(){
      this.sumaNumeros()
    }
   })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$numerosSumar = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$numeroUno = (int)$numerosSumar['numero1'];
$numeroDos = (int)$numerosSumar['numero2'];

echo $numeroUno + $numeroDos;
```

Sin embargo como pueden notar he tenido que extraer los valores con file_get_contents() e incluso añadir al inicio de cada valor la directiva de **int** para indicarle que son valores numéricos ya que de otro modo me muestra errores.

La pregunta o preguntas es: ¿cómo logro recibir los valores de manera individual del siguiente modo?

```
$numero1 = $_POST['numeroUno'];
```

para que de ese modo también evite el uso de json_decode() y de file_get_contents();

//ACTUALIZACIÓN

Si por ejemplo dentro de PHP asigno a cada variable los valores que llegan del formulario:

```
$numeroUno = $_POST['numero1'];
$numeroDos = $_POST['numero2'];

echo $numeroUno + $numeroDos;
```

El resultado que obtengo es un error de este tipo

> **Notice**: Undefined index: numero1 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax-axios\almacena.php** on line **5**
>   
>  **Notice**: Undefined index: numero2 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax-axios\almacena.php** on line **6**
>   0

Comment: Tu php esta devolviendo solo la suma de los numeros no? no deberias construir un json de respuesta con los dos valores?

Comment: si la suma la construye con los valores que le llegan del formulario HTML, pero al menos cuando lo intente solo me quedo haciendolo del modo en que posteo

Comment: es decir como extraigo u obtengo los dos valores que lleguen pero del modo que indico en la pregunta

Comment: y tu echo no deberia devolver un json? nunca vi que usaran php de backend, por eso pregunto

Comment: mi duda no es esa, mi duda es como obtener dichos valores del modo tradicional por asi decirlo $var = $_POST['valor1']; y no como lo he tenido que hacer

Comment: Ahhh tu problema esta del lado de php, no de axios ni vue. Listo ahi me quedo claro. Fijate q eso este clarito.

Comment: entonces como debería proceder para corregir ese detalle?

Comment: No conozco `Vue` ni `axios`... pero supongo que funcionan parecido a cualquier petición Ajax estándar. El `post` que has enviado al servidor, debería ser recuperado en alguna parte, supongo que aquí: `}).then((response) => {` en ese caso, el valor de `response` será lo que haya devuelto el servidor, sea un texto normal, o sea: `echo $numeroUno + $numeroDos;`, sea un JSON (que es mucho mejor), o cualquier otra cosa. Eso sí, conviene que haya una sola salida por pantalla, un sólo `echo`, no varios...

Comment: @A.Cedano agregue a mi pregunta el error que obtengo si hago cambios

Comment: Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42507767/5587982) deberías hacer algo así: `var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('numero1', this.numero1);
params.append('numero2', this.numero2);
axios.post('almacena.php', params) //...`

Comment: intentaré gracias

Comment: By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use one of the following options. Fijate en eso.. los parametros van en json por defecto, para cambiarlo tenes que seguir el manual https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un detalle de la forma en la cuál se envía los datos, haría falta crear un objeto `FormData` *(como solución más próxima)* para enviar a la petición de Axios y como posiblemente pueda que sea reutilizable en otros escenarios *( suponiendo un crud básico necesitarás el mismo formData)* si no podría hacerlo directamente en el método sumaNumeros.

Crearíamos un método `createdFormData` *(para el ejemplo)* donde iteramos sobre el objeto que tiene los atributos *(valores de entrada)*  y añadimos al `formData` . Ojo que el `v-model` ahora apuntará a cada propiedad  del objeto que utilizamos para crear el `formData`

HTML

```
<div id="app" >
    <form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent>
      <input type="text" v-model="objeto.numero1" name="numero1" />Primer Número
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" v-model="objeto.numero2" name="numero2" />Segundo Número
      <br><br>
      <button @click="sumaNumeros">Suma los Números</button>
    </form>
    {{ resultado }}
 </div>
```

**Vue**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
      objeto : {numero1: '', numero2: ''},
      resultado: ''
    },
    methods:{
      sumaNumeros: function(){
        axios.post('almacena.php',this.createdFormData())
        .then((response) => {
          this.resultado = response.data
        })
      },
    createdFormData : function (){
        var formDa = new FormData();
        for(var key in this.objeto){
            formDa.append(key, this.objeto[key]);
        }
        return formDa;
    },
    created: function(){
      this.sumaNumeros()
    }
   }
});
```

Con esto desde PHP accedería como siempre  a través de `$_POST` y `$_GET`

```
$numeroUno = (int)$_POST['numero1'];
```

Comment: gracias comprendí muy bien tu explicación y me soluciono la duda

Answer (score 2):

Podrías tratar utilizando la función publicada en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object).

Básicamente convierte el objeto a un query string. O como comento @gbianchi, la [documentación](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser) indica como solucionarlo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Hola</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app" >
    <form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent>
      <input type="text" v-model="numero1" name="numero1" />Primer Número
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" v-model="numero2" name="numero2" />Segundo Número
      <br><br>
      <button @click="sumaNumeros">Suma los Números</button>
    </form>
    {{ resultado }}
 </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
  var str = [],
    p;
  for (p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p,
        v = obj[p];
      str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
        serialize(v, k) :
        encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
}
   new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
      numero1: '',
      numero2: '',
      resultado: ''
    },
    methods:{
      sumaNumeros: function(){
        axios.post('almacena.php', serialize({
          numero1: this.numero1,
          numero2: this.numero2
        })).then((response) => {
          this.resultado = response.data
        })
      }
    },
    created: function(){
      this.sumaNumeros()
    }
   })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pero no es un error. es la forma en que manda los datos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar en tu archivo PHP:

```
$varPOST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
extract($varPOST);
```

Y usar los parametros del POST como variables.

Por ejemplo:

POST envia `{"numero":1}` y en el archivo PHP puedes usar la variable `$numero`